# How to reduce facial fat?

Tags: weight-loss, fat

I have been doing Insanity exercises for over a month now and couple with a strict, clean diet I have really seen improvements in my body. I have lost 7+ kgs of weight, my stomach has reduced and overall I feel fit. But the only thing which has not reduced is my double chin. They just seem to hang in there no matter how hard I workout!

Are there any exercises targeting double chin reduction?

Answer (score 1):

Keep going.

I know it sounds crummy but what your are asking about is something called [spot reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spot_reduction)

This has long been regarded as a myth but as the linked article states there is *some* evidence to the contrary. Only time will tell.

A month really isn't enough time to dramatically change your body fat in the way you want as the human body is remarkably good at adapting to environmental pressures placed upon it.
I assure you though, over time you will lose the excess fat if you keep up the exercise and maintain a healthy diet.